# AngularJs - Changing the value of property

Tags: angularjs

I am new to anuglar Js. I am trying to figure out How do i change the property value.

```
 $scope.dashboards = {
                        "1": {
                            "widgets": [{
                                "row": 0,
                                "col": 0,
                                "sizeX": 2,
                                "sizeY": 1,
                                "name": "Canvas 1",
                                "canvas": "canvas_1",
                                "show": true
                            }, {
                                "row": 0,
                                "col": 2,
                                "sizeX": 2,
                                "sizeY": 1,
                                "name": "Canvas 2",
                                "canvas": "canvas_2",
                                "show": true
                            }]
                            }
                     }
```

On ng-click , i want to change the value of key "show" to false.

```
<div gridster-item="widget" ng-repeat="widget in dashboard.widgets">
    <i ng-click="changeValue(widget)" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash">
</div>

$scope.changeValue= function (widget) {
            .....How to??
        };
```

Comment: do U want to change all show property value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are already passing the current widget as a parameter, you can do Like this

```
$scope.changeValue= function (widget) {
        widget.show = false;
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

I would not pass the widget. Instead I would pass its $index:

```
<i ng-click="changeValue($index)" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash">
```

And then:

```
$scope.changeValue= function (index) {
   $scope.dashboards.1.widgets[index].show = ...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It's look like your array in ng-repeat is undefined in scope.
You should update your codes like below;

```
<div gridster-item="widget" ng-repeat="widget in dashboards.1.widgets">
    <i ng-click="changeValue(widget)" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash">
</div>
```

After you get related object and update show property in `$scope` like below:

```
$scope.changeValue= function (widget) {
   $scope.dashboards.1.widgets[widget].show = false;      
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply,

```
$scope.changevalue= function(widget){
  for (var i = 0; i < $scope.dashboards.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < $scope.dashboards[i].widgets.length; j++) {
        if ($scope.dashboards[i].widgets[j].ID == widget.ID){
            $scope.dashboards[i].widgets[j].show= false
        }
    };  
  };      
}
```